# Search a hash for string with most vowels

Tags: ruby

So let's say I have a hash full of strings as the values. How would I make a method that will search the hash and return the string with the most vowels in it?

Comment: Using @MichałMłoźniak's answer and the suggestion by @MladenJablanović you could use: 
`hash.max_by { |key, value| value.scan(/[aeiou]/).size }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = nil
max = 0

# hash is your hash with strings
hash.values.each do |value|
  vowels = value.scan(/[aeiouy]/).size

  if vowels > max
    max = vowels
    result = value
  end
end

puts result
```

Comment: Have a look at `Enumerable#max_by` method.

Comment: What if there's a tie?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 The first occurence will be returned

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) and [String#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-count).

```
def most_vowel_laden(h)
  h.values.max_by { |str| str.count('aeiouAEIOU') }
end

keys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
h = keys.zip(%w| It was the best of times |).to_h
  #=> {1=>"it", 2=>"was", 3=>"the", 4=>"best", 5=>"of", 6=>"times"}
most_vowel_laden h
  #=> "times"

h = keys.zip(%w| by my dry fly why supercalifragilisticexpialidocious |).to_h
  #=> {1=>"by", 2=>"my", 3=>"dry", 4=>"fly", 5=>"why",
  #    6=>"supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"} 
most_vowel_laden h
  #=> "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious"
```

Alternatively,

```
def most_vowel_laden(h)
  h.max_by { |_,str| str.count('aeiouAEIOU') }.last
end
```

Comment: OP asks for a method that searches a hash no?

Comment: @sagarpandya82, whoops! Fixed. Thanks.